# Converting Python iterative function to recursive function

Tags: python-3.x

Please consider 2 crossed suites:

```
U0 = 1
V0 = 2
Un = 2U(n-1) + 3 V(n-1)
Vn = U(n-1) + V(n-1)
```

I want to resolve it with this Python iterative function:

```
def myfunction(n=5):
  u = 1
  v = 2
  for i in range(n):
    w = u
    u = 2*u + 3*v
    v = w + v
  
  return(u,v)
```

I would prefer a recursive function but I have no idea to  convert my function.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive recursive implementation proposed by @moctarjallo is very slow because the same values have to be calculated over and over again. For example, calculating `u(22)` takes the ridiculous 0.8 sec:

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit('u(22)', globals=globals(), number=10)
# 8.138428802136332
```

Consider using an `lru_cache` decorator that saves the previously computed values in an invisible table and actually calls the functions only when they have not been called with the same parameters before:

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(None) # decorate with a cache
def fast_u(n):
    return 1 if not n else 2 * fast_u(n-1) + 3 * fast_v(n-1)

@lru_cache(None) # decorate with a cache
def fast_v(n):
    return 2 if not n else fast_u(n-1) + fast_v(n-1)

timeit('fast_u(22)',globals=globals(), number=10)
#9.34056006371975e-05
```

I also made the functions code a little more idiomatic. Enjoy the difference!

P.S. If you are looking for a one-function implementation:

```
def uv(n):
    if n == 0: return 1, 2
    u, v = uv(n-1)
    return 2 * u + 3 * v, u + v
uv(5)
#(905, 393)
```

Caching still improves its performance by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Please add this as a new answer so i can upvote it.

Comment: Also i don't think performance is what mattered for OP at the time of asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
def u(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2*u(n-1) + 3*v(n-1)
    
def v(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 2
    else:
        return u(n-1) + v(n-1)

print((u(5), v(5))) # -> (905, 393)
```

This is possible due to the nature of Python being an **interpreted dynamic** programing language.

**Edit:**

```
def myfunction(n):
    def u(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2*u(n-1) + 3*v(n-1)
        
    def v(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 2
        else:
            return u(n-1) + v(n-1)
    return u(n), v(n)

print(myfunction(5)) # -> (905, 393)
```

Just to conform with your exact problem/function.

Comment: Oh well that's one tiny step away he could figure out. Or i can still edit.

Comment: Thanks. In fact it's to illustrate an algorithmic problem so not necessary use Python. Python only helps me to solve it. So is it not possible with only ONE function?

Comment: @Theo yeah this wouldn't be possible with a **static programming language* like Java, or C++ because the compiler would complain for *v* not defined while defining *u* (i.e static checking)

Comment: A one-function imlementation is possible and in fact quite elegant. See my updated answer,

Comment: "This wouldn't be possible with a *static programming language like Java, or C++" - this is not true. Both Java and C++ allow mutually recursive functions. This has nothing to do with the dynamic and interpreted nature of the language.